# Bash : want to use jq library to insert field into existing json file containing array of json object

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I am new to bash scripting initial data

```
$jq_linux64 -n '.Data.Info = []' > input.json
```

later I insert data like below

for this I have written here ${3} is input.json

```
cat ${3} | $jq_linux64 --arg tranID "${1}" \
                       --arg architectureType "${2}" \
           '.Data.Info += [{"tranID": ($tranID),"architecture": ($architecture)}]'\ >tmp.json && mv tmp.json ${3}
```

which will generate following

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Info": [
      {
        "tranID": "1",
        "architecture": "thread_1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

now I want write various functions ( which will gets called from another bash scripts"  to insert data in LAST object of JSON array

```
insertbuildinfo()
{

}
```

which should modify above input.jason like

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Info": [
      {
        "tranID": "1",
        "architecture": "thread_1",
        "build": "yes"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

again next function will insert "win" field with it's value input.json

```
nextfunc()
{
}


{
  "Data": {
    "Info": [
      {
        "tranID": "1",
        "architecture": "thread_1",
        "build": "yes",
        "win": "qaw"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

final JSON should be

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Info": [
      {
        "tranID": "1",
        "architecture": "thread_1",
        "build": "yes",
        "win": "qaw"
      },
      {
        "tranID": "2",
        "architecture": "thread_2",
        "build": "yes",
        "win": "qaw"
      },
      {
        "tranID": "3",
        "architecture": "thread_3",
        "build": "yes",
        "win": "qaw"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

wanted to insert new field in last object of array

Please help me in writing jq functions since I am completely new to this topic 
any help is appreciated.

Comment: Format code by 4 spaces indent **or** by three backticks. And ***NOT*** by 8 spaces **and** three backticks.

Comment: Is a space missing in `--arg tranID"${1}"`?

Comment: KamilCuk corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to understand some `jq`. Inserting a field to the last element of an array is simple:

```
jq '.Data.Info[-1] += { "build": "yes" }'
```

Comment: to append I am using cat command like............                                               cat input.json  > jq '.Data.Info[-1] += { "build": "yes" }'      but not working

Comment: Well, stackoverflow is not a place to learn programming. And `not working` is a very vague description. [Bash tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+tutorial) can be found in various places on the net, be sure to check [bashfaq](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F002.How_can_I_store_the_return_value_and.2For_output_of_a_command_in_a_variable.3F). You can `jq .Data.Info[-1] += { "build": "yes" }' input.json > sometempfile; mv sometempfile input.json`. But I would just keep it in memory `data=$(<input.json); data=$(jq '.Data.Info[-1] += { "build": "yes" }' <<<"$data") ...`